# how to select cell focused cell Value by focusing in Cell in grid view

Tags: c#, xtragrid

I want that when I enter in any cell of gridview then that cell value should be selected.

Meana focused cell value should be selected on focusing in Gridview Cells.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
OptionsBehavior.EditorShowMode
```

Solution for your problem is [Here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A277.aspx)